# Не срабатывает OnGlobalLayoutListener при использовании ViewPager

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-viewpager

У меня есть фрагмент с таким методом onCreateView

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = FragmentMapBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    
    binding.root.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            Log.i("TAG", "On Global Layout")
        }
    })

    return binding.root
}
```

я использую экземпляры этого фрагмента в адаптере для viewPager

```
    class MapPagerAdapter(
    _fragment: Fragment,
    _placeMapList: MutableList<PlaceMap>
) : FragmentStateAdapter(_fragment) {

    var placeMapList = _placeMapList

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return placeMapList.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return MapFragment.newInstance(placeMapList[position])
    }

}
```

Однако при запуске приложения у меня срабатывает onGlobalLayout только для первого фрагмента, который показывает viewPager, почему так происходит